Broken 'Activities overview' after suspension in the Ubuntu 24.04
Could anybody help me to figure out how to fix Activities overview in Ubuntu 24.04, after Suspend/Hibernate mode it doesn't work - when I press the Super button it shows an empty window. The mouse isn't able to select the Search field, but even I type the app name it isn't shown, no icons just an empty screen:

I've tested it with different Nvidia drivers and event both types of GUI - Xorg and Wayland, but the same issue.

any help or update with this? I have the same issue (upgraded from 22 to 24.04)  and the preview of apps is obvious.

I've reinstalled back Ubuntu 22. But I've found that such an issue could happen (very rarely) in the previous version. In Ubuntu 22 I've "Suspended", or "Logged out", and "Logged in" as Xorg GUI (not as Wayland), which can be recognized as a bit smaller inputs of user/password fields. And Search works fine. Unfortunately, the same workaround doesn't work on Ubuntu 24, I hope it will be fixed in the next release because it is a crucial bug!

Same issue after update from 22.04

Yes, same here.  Nvidia drivers with exactly the screen you see.  I think our questions are similar, but perhaps not identical.  See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1527160/upon-upgrade-to-24-04-system-suspends-properly-but-no-desktop-icons-on-waking

Work around:
I've installed the apps Menu extension.
Edit:
I continued investigating my issue and found this post. It suggested that the issue might be with a gnome extension. I Experimented a bit and discovered that in my case, the issue was caused by the Dash to Panel extension. Upon deactivating it and logging back in, the issue was no longer present.
