Upon upgrade to 24.04, system suspends properly, but no desktop icons on waking
Today I upgraded Ubuntu from 22.04 to 24.04.  After resuming from suspend there are no desktop icons, however I can bring up the command window. There is no launcher, no activities icon. In order to see the desktop files, the launcher and the activities icon, I have to restart the system. All the files are in the Desktop directory, but the desktop screen has nothing but the top banner. Do you have any ideas?  Also this isn't a laptop.
Here are system details. They are identical both after a restart and after a return from suspend.

Here's a link to the file from journalctl:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EphxgCb6SuPiAYoxs8jcOE1_ZMJHOAd6/view?usp=sharing
I have looked through this file and do not see any problems waking from suspend.  Indeed, the system wakes, but the icons, launcher and activities icon are not there.  If I press the upper left hand elongated horizontal oval shape next to the dot (new in 24.04) on the top across from logout, shutdown and settings, I can see other applications that were minimized before suspend--resume.  Therefore, it looks like all active applications stay alive and accessible, but nothing else.
I'm wondering if this has anything to do with Nvidia graphics and Suspend.  The driver and suspend have given me trouble before, but I really don't know how to approach this issue without expert help.
Here's another hint: if I suspend while a window is open (e.g., Vivaldi), when I later resume the system, that window is still there and operating normally.  The Launcher, Activities icon and all the desktop icons are missing.
Someone in comments suggested this might be the same as another problem where Noble was needed, not Jammy.  My problem is very different than the problems in "Major software missing after 24.04 LTS upgrade." Noble is there correctly, not jammy and also, the GUI comes up just fine upon restart, but not after waking from suspend.
Switched to NVIDIA 535 driver(proprietary) from Nouveau.  Same problem.
A workaround is to logout and then log back in again.  You lose everything open, but at least suspend/resume works.

Wait, now the launcher is gone too.  All I have is the top panel upon waking.

After waking from suspend, please go to your system settings and then select "details" or select "about this computer" from one of your main menus. This should display stuff like Memory, Processor, Graphics, etc. Take note of these results (it would also help to edit your question and include this information). Then, repeat this process after you boot up normally without suspend. I am interested to know if like the Graphics is different when you wake up from suspend (maybe it's not initializing correctly and falling back to sort of a low graphics mode).

Also, run the command sudo journalctl -b | grep -i error or simply run journalctl -b or sudo journalctl -b and scroll down to the end to look for any logs that might indicate there was a problem waking up from suspend.

This question is similar to: Major software missing after 24.04.1 LTS upgrade. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You have solved?

Adding options nvidia NVreg_PreserveVideoMemoryAllocations=1 to modprobe.d like it is described here, fixed it for me (Ubuntu 2404, Gnome 46, Wayland, Nvidia 550).

I struggled with suspend/resume in that the login screen was garbled, didn't show most of the characters. Still I could login, but problems continued in different ways on the desktop.
Problems started, after switching to "NVIDIA driver metapackage from nvidia-driver-550(proprietary, tested)". But I remember facing the same problem with earlier versions.
It seems to be fixed, after:

cd /etc/modprobe.d
sudo cp nvidia-graphics-drivers-kms.conf nvidia-graphics-drivers-kms.conf.back
sudo vi nvidia-graphics-drivers-kms.conf
change: options nvidia-drm modeset=1
into: options nvidia-drm modeset=0
sudo update-initramfs -u
sudo reboot

